# CentOS7 extend display, two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, xrandr

I am new to CentOS7 and I am trying to extend my display. I have an Intel graphics chip. I connected the second display to the same graphics card and it is currently only mirroring the first display. I can find no evidence that the system even recognized it as a second screen. What do I have to do to use the second screen as extension?

Desktop environment: GNOME and XFCE
Kernel: 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
One screen is connected to a DisplayPort and one to DVI.
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)

When running

```
xrandr -q
```

I get this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050      0.00*
   1280x1024      0.00
   1024x768       0.00
   800x600        0.00
   640x480        0.00
```

Comment: What PC/laptop/motherboard/cpu? How do you connect? Which desktop environment are you using? Kernel version?

Comment: Desktop environment: GNOME and XFCE
Kernel: 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
One screen is connected to a DisplayPort and one to DVI.
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)

Answer (score 0):

I updated with
`yum --enablerepo=cr update` as suggested in the CentOS community. After a reboot it actually worked.